# Features often disappear in attribute table when edited

Tags: qgis, shapefile, editing

using the most recent QGIS version, currently 2.18.3 on win64, I regularly experienced the issue that features disappear in attribute table with no reason after I made and saved edits. Fortunately, these features are not gone permanently (they just are not displayed in attribute table). Reloading the shapefiles usually fixes the issue, but it is very annoying and causes fears, data could be lost. I did not set filters or definition queries at all. This behavior happens on all my machines and has happened for at least two years. What could cause this behavior and how could I solve it?

Comment: Maybe something in your settings? Under extra-->settings/options (don't know what it is in english) --> datasources there is an option called "atributetable behavior". Make sure that is set to 'show all objects'. If that doesn't work, maybe some other setting in that options menu that may solve it?

Comment: Thanks, it is set to that setting. Due to the inconsistent behavior I´m sure it´s due to the editing process. Maybe a bug since the features not displayed in attribute table are still present on the map canvas

Comment: I have found this: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/10976. It's kind of the similar problem you are having.

Comment: I wonder why this ticket is closed

Answer (score 1):

In older versions of QGIS, the attribute table wouldn't refresh when editing a layer. It was necessary to close the attribute table and open it again to see changes made during editing. Since QGIS 2.14, it is possible to manually refresh the attribute table. (See [image from QGIS 2.14 changelog on qgis.com](http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog214/index.html#id88))
[image: image from QGIS 2.14 changelog on qgis.com]

Two closed [reports](http://hub.qgis.org) of similar issues dealt with earlier versions of QGIS. If the issue persists in 2.18, please submit a new bug report.

https://hub.qgis.org/issues/11939

https://hub.qgis.org/issues/10976